# Autoscrolling UITextView (like in the SMS app)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have a `UITextView` in my app. I want to be able to scroll the `UITextView` after certain no of lines being entered into the `UITextView`, like the iPhone's sms app.

Currently I have the below code:

```
myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(45, 50, 250, 20);
    myTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    myTextView.delegate = self;
    myTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    myTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    myTextView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myTextView];
```

Comment: Do you want the text inside the view to scroll or the entire UITextView object to scroll on the screen? Please clarify what you are looking to do.

Comment: `Like the Messages.app` means to me that the text is ought to scroll. Do you want it to scroll or to become higher like the `Messages.app`?

Comment: yes it has to scroll after 4 lines ( after given no of lines , it has to scroll )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out UIScrollView's `setContentOffset:animated`.

For example, to scroll all the way to the bottom of the screen, you would do:

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height);
[scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```